# How to write a function to Generate String like A0001, A0002, ..A9999,... AA0001, AA9999,... AZ0001, AZ9999,

Tags: php, mysql

How to write a function in PHP to Generate String like 
A0001, A0002, ..A9999,... AA0001, AA9999,... AZ0001, AZ9999,...

Also if its possible to write a function in mysql please let me to know.

I am going to Define the Unique ID for records in database,
so i need to generate Unique ID.
right now i am using auto increment on table. now its touch 8 digit, so i need to minimize it with 4 to 6 digits. one of my friend said use this formula so you will minimize your length of unique id.

```
A9999 = 9,999 Records
AA0001 to AZ9999 = 259,974 Records
AA0001 to ZZ9999 = 175,742,424 Records
```

or else if you have any other ideas, please give it to me.

Thanks in advance.

**GOT SOLUTION FOR MY ISSUE**

Thanks to your suggestion and idea, with @thecoshman helps i solved my issues Virtually.

```
function encodeItemBarcode($number) {
    $number = base_convert($number, 10, 36);
    $number = strtoupper($number);
    return $number;
}
function decodeItemBarcode($number) {
    $number = base_convert($number, 36, 10);
    $number = strtoupper($number);
    return $number;
}
```

Output:

```
999999999991 Encrypted as : CRE66I9J - Decrypted as : 999999999991
999999999992 Encrypted as : CRE66I9K - Decrypted as : 999999999992
999999999993 Encrypted as : CRE66I9L - Decrypted as : 999999999993
999999999994 Encrypted as : CRE66I9M - Decrypted as : 999999999994
999999999995 Encrypted as : CRE66I9N - Decrypted as : 999999999995
999999999996 Encrypted as : CRE66I9O - Decrypted as : 999999999996
999999999997 Encrypted as : CRE66I9P - Decrypted as : 999999999997
999999999998 Encrypted as : CRE66I9Q - Decrypted as : 999999999998
999999999999 Encrypted as : CRE66I9R - Decrypted as : 999999999999
```

So Finally i minimized 12 Digit(999999999991) into 8 Char(CRE66I9J). I am not going to store it in database, i am going to use this in Front End only.

Once again Thanks to All.

Comment: you need to clarify the the transition from A9999. What should follow? AA0001 or B0001?

Comment: also what should follow after A0009? A0010 or A000A?

Comment: This looks like an attempt at a brute force generator...

Comment: @BrianGraham not that much really. Plus, looking at the OP's history on SO, it seems legit enough to me

Comment: If you need an ID for record in a database, why not just let it use an integer? why are you trying to reduce the number of digits used?

Comment: Brothers please read my modifications. thanks to all

Comment: your edit doesnt clarify the transitions

Comment: You know, more digits does not equate to more bits used to store them? I think what you are look at is storing a STRING representation as hex rather then decimal, but this is moot, as an ID field should be a number not a string

Comment: @ thecoshman, dear sir, you dont understand, my client dont want to 8 digit or 10 digit or 15 digit ID (for Reference) he need 4 to 8 Digit Reference only. so the Primary ID is integer with auto increment. this is for reference.

Comment: @rkaartikeyan so the database has nothing to do with this at all. It can still store the ID as an int. You just need a function to convert the high order digits to (what I believe to be) a hex representation

Comment: @ thecoshman, exactly right brother.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you could just get away with displaying the decimal ID number as a hex value, so if you had the value 3397 it would display in it's hex form of D45. With this sytem, a maximum of 6 hex digits, FFFFFF would equal a decimal value of 16777215

That would be the limit of Using hex and only displaying 6 digits.

If you need to be able to 'represent' larger numbers, I can provide a solution. Though the easiest one I can think of would be something like using base 36, ie 0 to 1 is 0 to 9, and then it continues, like hex, A to Z is 10 to 35. such the Z + 1 = A0 or 36. It will take a bit for me to think this out, so I don't want to bother if it is not what you need, just let me know via comment